# How to iterate over a JSON returned array in freemarker?

Tags: json, freemarker

I have a JSON array in this format :

```
{
"productList" : [
{
        "nodeRef"           : "workspace:\/\/SpacesStore\/55f8dd88-dccd-4c09-9a67-bb3f2d5f02d4",
    "photoProduit"      : "api\/node\/workspace\/SpacesStore\/60f80999-0d2b-4798-abbb-786d5fe13a85\/content\/thumbnails\/doclib",
    "typeProduit"       : "Bonbon",
    "uniteQuantite"     : "48",
    "tarifUnitaire"     : "1.89",
    "descriptionProduit": "Sweets product update test 2"
}
        ,
{
        "nodeRef"           : "workspace:\/\/SpacesStore\/c2ffb3c1-9091-47fb-9b01-ce6b0d30a869",
    "photoProduit"      : "api\/node\/workspace\/SpacesStore\/77264862-54a4-4248-acf0-8e36c400dc1a\/content\/thumbnails\/doclib",
    "typeProduit"       : "Post It Notes",
    "uniteQuantite"     : "10",
    "tarifUnitaire"     : "2.76",
    "descriptionProduit": "Post It Notes"
}

]
}
```

I'm unsure of how I can access the array elements as the productList is a hash. Is it possible to parse this in freemarker, as Hashes don't have much built ins and I cannot seem to apply sequence built-ins to the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`productList` is not a hash, it's a sequence (a list). So, if you have `productList` in the FreeMarker variable `productList`, you could do something like:

```
<#list productList as product>
  ${product.nodeRef}
</#list>
```

Comment: that didn't work unfortunately. It was an oversight on my part. I forgot that I had to access it via the model object in which the return was assigned in my application.

Comment: I am accepting this as an answer with this little addendum to help explain in case someone else is caught out the same way; because the return is assigned to a root scope object(in my case this was also named "productList"), the correct syntax was to use <root-scope-object>["productList"]; so <#list productList["productList"] as product> to be more specific

Comment: If you only have `productList` in the top-level JSON map, then add that to the data-model instead of the map itself. Or, use the map itself as the data-model. In both cases you avoid having a `productList` inside a `productList`. BTW, you can write `productList["productList"]` simply as `productList.productList`.